# Ubuntu 18.04 auto move same applications at startup to different work spaces and start scripts

Tags: 18.04, gnome-terminal, startup, ubuntu-gnome, window

I want to accomplish the following:

On start up the following applications should open up on the following work spaces

- Work space 01

  - gnome-terminal, not maximized
- Work space 02

  - gnome-terminal, maximized
- Work space 03

  - Mozilla Firefox, maximized

Problem: this does not seem possible with the means I have been trying. A secondary problem is being able to start specific scripts in said terminals (tmux, other scripts I have written, etc.)

Trouble shooting:

- I tried using "Auto Move Windows" however this tool will move any application to defined Workspace even if it is the same application. So when I set terminal to be on work space 01 and 02, it moves both to work space 02
- Tried figuring out DevilsPie2 however I am not sure this is the answer either as I am not sure how to identify each window. Would rather not use this tool if I do not have to.

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

For your scenario, it suffices to have a startup script that launches and positions these applications. That startup script could then start your terminal on the first workspace, then move to the second workspace, start the terminal and maximize it, then move to workspace 3 and start firefox.

A tool that allows you to do these manipulations is `wmctrl`. You can switch to a specific desktop, you can move windows to specific desktops, and you can manipulate windows such as maximize them, minimize them, undecorate them... See `man wmctrl` for documentation. You can find many examples on the internet.

Once you have a working script, you can have it start up automatically on login..

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a workaround for my purposes. I ended up installing Guake terminal.

Guake is a terminal tray which can be slid out or hidden. I can run both Guake and gnome-terminal at start up on workspace 1. Then I run my scripts inside of Guake terminal, open gnome-terminal and run a script, and finally hide Guake terminal. This worked for me.